# Python List output help needed

Tags: python, list, pycharm

Could somebody explain me why am I getting this output from the Python list?

```py
>>> lst = [3, 1, -2]
>>> print(lst[lst[-1]])  *# prints index position [1]*
1
>>> print(lst[lst[-2]])  *# prints index position [1]*`
1
```

Comment: lst[index] give the value stored in the list at the particular index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lst[-1] gets first element from right  so -2 in this case

lst[-2] gets second element from right which is 1

so lst[[lst[-1]] will be equalent to lst[-2]
lst[lst[-2]] will be equalent to lst[1]

and lst[-2] gets second element from right which is 1
and ls[1] gets element at index 1 ( which is 1

Answer (score 0):

`lst[lst[x]]` uses the `x`:th value to look up another value.

`lst[-2]` means the second element from the end. `lst[1]` is `-2` so `lst[lst[1]]` prints that element.

`lst[1]` means the second element from the beginning (remember that Python indices start at 0). `lst[-2]` is `1` so `lst[lst[-2]]]` prints that element.

Answer (score 0):

`lst[-1]` will return the last element in the list which is -2.

`lst[-2]` will return the second from last element which is 1

`lst[-2]` (the second from last item in lst) is 1.

`lst[1]` (the second item in the list) is also 1.